# How did Vasco da Gama know about the Southern Cross?

Tags: age-of-discovery, astronomy, navigation

It is said that the precession cycle of the Earth's axis takes about 26,000 years to complete. It is also said that the ancient Greeks could see **Crux** (aka **the Southern Cross**) from where they lived. It is a constellation resembling a cross:

[image]

It is also believed that Vasco da Gama was the first European in a long time to see it as he traveled south along the African coast, but he somehow ***expected*** to see it. There were rumors and legends about it.

Wouldn't this mean that he, and the astronomers of his time, knew about precession (almost a century before the advent of Kepler's and Galileo's theories)?

Comment: Why don't you ask ONE question at a time? What is the relation between precession and Southern cross? If you look at a map (where the Greeks lived and still live) you will immediately see that they could not see Southern cross.

Comment: @Alex He has a single question. He merely proposes his own answer and is in doubt about it. It is correct and allowed here. The real problem of QA is in logic, but being illogical is not forbidden on the StackExchange sites.

Comment: The Southern Cross is visible above the latitude of the equator.

Comment: I still don't see what all this has to do with precession, and still assert that Greeks could not see S. Cross (from where they live).

Comment: Don't see why this question deserves a negative score...

Comment: @NeMo I agree.  I think this is a very good question.  I give up trying to figure this site out.

Comment: Precession is describes in Claudius Ptolemy's Almagest , as is Crux (as part of Centaurus). The Almagest was still the main source of astronomical knowledge up to the 16th C. Crux had been visible from Athens ~1000 BCE but did not rise above the horizon there by 400 CE. But then Ptolemy lived and worked in Egypt.

Comment: @ConradTurner: And you couldn't say all this earlier. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace "it is believed" about da Gama being the first to see the Cross should be read as "I believe", that would be honest. But "it is said" about 26000y precession as absolutely correct. We needn't write references about the common knowledge.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace 1. If somebody questions the correctness of the supposedly common knowledge, an additional question in a comment could be put. Really, we can't give reference to every outspoken or hidden base sentence. 2.I have seen many times on the sites of StackExchange, how an obviously false sentence was put and supported by an obviously false reference or a reference not proving the base sentence. And readers are mostly too lazy to check. So, sorry, by itself the fact of reference support does NOT mean quality post. Only support of GOOD references does.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace There are people that believe in Flat Earth. If I will write a post with senseless sentences, based on references to those articles, will it mean a good post? ... Anyway, I could understand downvote on this QA, because of it bad logic (knowledge precession cannot not explain knowledge on the Cross). But I forgave that mistake, done obviously due to limited knowledge in the subj. And, as I said, I agree with you about obviously dishonest sentence "da Gama is believed to be the first to see the Cross". But that piece about precession sounds absolutely OK to me. And I UPvoted.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace BTW, your most upvoted answer https://history.stackexchange.com/a/39928/566 has HEAPS of statements not supported by any reference. As for me, it is OK. (due to common knowledge). And for you?

Comment: @Gangus  - I'm going to delete my comment; the last sentence was intended to poke fun at myself. Re-reading it, I see that it came across confrontational, when I intended humor.  SOrry about that.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace 1. Thank you for edition (but I am trying to use BrEn, so, for me they are catalogues). 2. Thank you for your kind upvoting - I am glad when I can protect somebody. 3. I didn't took it confrontational, I simply didn't understood it and was foolish enough for not to ask back.

Comment: Good question.+1. First what is precession is the matter to me lol.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In 1460, at the time of the death of Prince Henry, the Navigator, the Portuguese had mapped the western coast of Africa [down to the 8 N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Portugal_(1415%E2%80%931578)#Chronology_of_the_Portuguese_discoveries) parallel. The Southern Cross is well seen at this latitude. Really, all stars can be seen between the tropics, and the Northern Tropic was reached even earlier. In 1471, they crossed the Equator and began to be guided by Crux.

And Vasco da Gama's travel started in 1497. Of course, he expected and simply knew he would see the Southern Cross. Europeans had looked at it for more than 40 years already. He counted on it. He was well prepared to use it for navigation, as they already did. Only the Cross was higher in the sky for him, than for his predecessors, thus being in the more convenient position.

And even if he were the first European to see it, he would simply have heard about the Cross from Arab sailors. And buy navigation charts from them, that would say how to use the Southern Cross for the Southern Pole placement. (It is not so simple as with the Polar Star)

The two pieces of knowledge - about the existence of Cross and about the precession - are practically independent. Or worse than independent, because the precession means that in a thousand years the points of North/South will move noticeably. So, if da Gama had information about usability of Southern Cross in the far past, and used precession data, he would conclude that the Cross is NOT usable now.

And yes, Europeans knew about precession for minimally 13 centuries at that moment, for already Ptolemy used it to wrongly fake his catalogue on the base of Hipparchos catalogue. *[History of Star Catalogs](http://www.taas.org/TheTAASFiles/Submittals/HistoryOfStarCatalogs.pdf), page 5*

Comment: great answer. people are often not told that navigating to India was the result of a multi-generational national effort, not just of one lucky stroke or an individual hero accomplishment.